# How can I set SSH connection to my server via just OPENVPN

Tags: security, networking, ssh, openvpn

I want to connect to my server via limited ip adresses. I thought that may be I can connect to my server via OPENVPN that is installed on my server. I have modified hosts.allow and hosts.deny files in /etc

---

### /etc/hosts.allow file :

### sshd : x.x.x.x (server ip )

### /etc/hosts.deny file :

### sshd : ALL

But I cant connect to my server via OpenVPN at the moment. OpenVPN has different ip adress like 10.8.0.x. 
How I can set SSH connection to my server via OpenVpn?

Comment: You can only block connections on IP level if you are getting a static IP address by the OpenVPN server (otherwise you have to allow a whole subnet). Anyway blocking IP addresses is the wrong way. Just change the SSH authentication to only accept public key authentication and use your private key for login. Then password breaking is no longer possible.

Comment: I modified sshd file. :I set " PasswordAuthentication no " and I can connect to server with public key but I want to learn how can I connect via defined ip adresses and also openVpn. Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ListenAddress` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to force SSHD to only listen on a specific IP address, namely the OpenVPN private address of your server, e.g.:

```
ListenAddress 10.8.0.1
```

This prevents sshd from listening on any other interfaces, including the public ones (by default sshd listens on all the available interfaces). Just make sure you restart sshd after updating the configuration.

After that to connect to SSH you will need to first establish the OpenVPN connection and then ssh into 10.8.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest using iptables to limit IP addresses

```
iptables -A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Comment: Yes this is also nice method. Thank you.